# como se relaciona .resolve() y .reject() con .then() y .catch()

Tags: javascript, asincronismo, programacion-asincrona

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y justo ahora me topo con asincronismo que apenas estoy comenzando a saber como funciona, la cosa es que todavía no logro entender muy bien para que sirve `.resolve()` y como se relaciona con `.then()`, al igual que `.reject()` y `.catch()`, entiendo que resolve es cuando la promesa se resuelve con éxito y reject cuando se rechaza, lo que pienso es que resolve y reject es como cuando pasamos una función dentro de otro, que solo son el nombre y dentro tienen el método `.then()` y `.catch()` respectivamente, pero al ver que resolve y reject tienen paréntesis por ende son funciones y me hace pensar que estoy equivocado, alguien tiene alguna idea?

ADJUNTO MI CÓDIGO.

```
function getPersonaje(id) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const personaje = `${API_URL}${PEOPLE_URL.replace(':id', id)}`;

    // $.get permite hacer un request.
    $.get(personaje, opts, function(data) {
            resolve(data)
        })
        .fail(() => reject(id));
});
}

function onError(id) {
    console.log(`Sucedio un error al obtener el personaje ${id}`)
}

getPersonaje(1)
    .then(function(personaje) {
        console.log(`Hola soy ${personaje.name}`)
    })
.catch(onError);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Resolve` y `reject` son parámetros de una callback con el que se construye una `Promise`, y así como has dicho una se relaciona con `then` y otra con `catch`, donde resolve sirve para retornar o no un valor cuando no han ocurrido errores.

Mientras que catch sirve para atrapar o arrojar el error obtenido.

> Cabe aclarar que `resolve` y `reject` funcionan como retornos, es
> decir, es prácticamente el equivalente a la sentencia `return` pero
> para una promise, la diferencia es que al invocarse las callbacks
> `resolve` y `reject` que provee la misma promise, le estamos diciendo
> a ésta qué camino debe tomar, ya sea devolvernos un error o
> devolvernos un valor, por lo tanto el objetivo de `.then` y `.catch`
> es manejar el código asíncrono, de tal forma que controlemos tanto los
> errores como la ejecución y el fin de la promise. De esta manera, la
> promise sabrá qué hacer y en qué momento terminará una vez finalizada, también sabrá qué valor retornar una vez se haya terminado de ejecutar.
>
> Si no colocamos resolve ni reject, la promise nunca será resuelta
> ni rechazada, teniendo así una promise infinita, una promise que
> estará en su estado `Promise<pending>` durante el resto de su
> eternidad, por lo tanto si tenemos una promise infinita al usar `.then` y `.catch` no se entraría nunca ni al uno ni al otro y la promise nunca retornaría ni un valor ni un error.

Así que `.then` y `.catch` se pueden encadenar, para siempre tener en cuenta ambas posibilidades (entrar al `then` si la promesa se resolvió con éxito o ir al `catch` si la promesa fue rechazada).

Con respecto a si `.then` y `.catch` son funciones te equivocas, éstos son métodos, debido que hacen parte de la instancia de una clase `Promise`.

Entonces tomemos de ejemplo este fragmento de código:

```
getPersonaje(1)
    .then(function(personaje) {
        console.log(`Hola soy ${personaje.name}`)
    })
.catch(onError);
```

Ahí mismo podemos ver cómo dependiendo de un parámetro la promesa se resuelve o se rechaza, en caso de que se resuelva se procede a obtener por medio de una callback en `.then` el resultado retornado por la promise, que en este caso el resultado se llama `personaje` y se imprime.

Por otro lado, en caso de haber error no estás haciendo nada, puesto que el `.catch` también debería ser un callback, así que yo en el `.catch` pondría algo como esto:

```
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Donde `e => console.log(e)` no es mas que una función flecha minimizada.

Por lo tanto, lo has entendido bien la forma en la que `.then` y `.catch` se relacionan, solo tenías un pequeño error de concepto, nada más.

¿Quizá quisiste ser mas específico con respecto a algún detalles más a fondo que no entiendas? Creo que lo has entendido bien.

Bueno, un detalle extra que te quiero comentar para que lo tengas en mente, y es que desde hace relativamente un tiempo existen algo llamado `funciones asíncronas`, las cuales no son mas que el **wrapper** de una `promise`, una peculiaridad que existe de las funciones asíncronas es que sea que tú le pongas un `return` o no a la `función asíncrona` ésta siempre va a devolver una promise.

Por lo tanto, veamos un ejemplo de función asíncrona y sus posibles usos con `await`:

```js
async function makeTransaction(){
  
  return await new Promise((res, rej) =>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      res(true);
    },2000);
  });
  
}

makeTransaction().then((transactionExited)=>{
  console.log(transactionExited);
});
```

Como vemos podemos usar algo nuevo **SOLO EN LAS FUNCIONES ASÍNCRONAS** y es la palabra reservada `await`, además ésta **NO** puede ser usada en el contexto global.

La palabra reservada `await` tiene como objetivo obligar a la función asíncrona a esperar ya sea el error o el valor obtenido, por lo tanto lo que hace es pausar la ejecución de la función y luego cuando la promise de la cual estamos intentando obtener un valor haya sido resuelta o rechazada la reanuda y nos devuelve el valor donde queremos.

De esta manera podemos organizar de mejor forma nuestro código, por supuesto lo ideal es no usar funciones asíncronas para código que es síncrono, pero en caso de que estemos manejando código asíncrono y multiples llamadas asíncronas es súper recomendable utilizar funciones asíncronas, pues en ese caso `await` nos hace la vida más fácil.

Comment: Genial amigo muchas gracias, la verdad me aclaraste todo bastante, como dices tenia un poco el concepto pero lo estaba visualizando mal, ahora puedo seguir aprendiendo javaScript.

Comment: +1 Estupenda respuesta, @Riven. Sólo un detalle, `...catch(onError)` ya está bien porque pasa como argumento la función `onError` del post original del OP. Por otra parte, `...catch(e => console.log(e))` es redundante y se puede reescribir como `...catch(console.log)` por la misma razón.

Comment: @VRoxa, si tienes razon, ya que haciendolo de esa manera le estarias pasando direcamtente al `console.log` como parametro el error, aunque no estoy muy acostumbrado a verlo de esa forma, quiza por eso se me ocurrio poner una funcion flecha, gracias por la edicion y el aporte `VRoxa`.

Comment: Por cierto Emmanuel, de nada amigo, si te ha ayudado mi respuesta recuerda que puedes darla como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo, asi tanto tu como yo ganaremos puntos en el sitio, tu por dar por concluida una respuesta y yo por responder a tu pregunta.